# How to populate a Tree View with class variables (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, treeview

I have an object which I am using to hold output data from a simulation. I'd like to populate a TreeView with the public properties of this object, but since I feel that I may add or remove members from this object, it makes sense to me to "bind" the object in some way such that the TreeView logic doesn't need to be manually updated with the object's properties.

As an example, let's say I have a class called `Temperature`, as follows:

```
public class Temperature
{
  public double Wall { get; set; }
  public double Floor { get; set; }

  public Temperature()
  {
    Wall = 0d;
    Floor = 0d;
  }
}
```

So I would like the TreeView to have a root node named Temperature, followed by child nodes named Wall and Floor. My current understanding would be to just hard code it, e.g.:

```
TreeNode tnTemperatureParent = treeViewData.Nodes.Add("Temperature");
tnTemperatureParent.Nodes.Add("Wall");
tnTemperatureParent.Nodes.Add("Floor");
```

Now, let's say I have to add a public property named `Ceiling` to the `Temperature` class. I would have to go to my TreeView logic and add a line to include a child node for `Ceiling`.

This all seems well and good for small datasets and primitive datatypes, but I need a higher degree of control here. The objects I wish to populate the TreeView with will end up holding more information, such as lists which I would like to use to plot. I'm looking at something around 50+ output variables, and it may be decided before completion that we want a few more, or a few less.

So, in summary, I suppose I have two questions here:

A) What is the optimal way to populate a TreeView with the public properties of an object?
B) Should I store the data as part of the TreeNodes (e.g. using the `Tag` property) or should I have the tree structure reference the object in parallel?

**EDIT**: I'm still fairly new at the whole object-oriented paradigm (started as a procedural programmer), so I have a hard time visualizing at times. Here's some additional information that may help understand the direction I'm going in.

During a simulation I've written, I hold time-step quantities in an "output data" class. The class is broken into subclasses (e.g. temperature, pressure), each which have a few parameters (e.g. wall, floor, ceiling in the example above). The reason I'd like to dump them into a TreeView is so that I can configure drag-drop functionality, allowing me to drag a data parameter (e.g. Floor Temperature) onto another control (such as a plot, or a table) such that the data can be presented. I hope that helps.

Comment: windows forms or wpf?

Comment: Ahh, should have mentioned that. WinForms.

Comment: Dupe I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880930/easy-object-binding-to-treeview-node

Comment: Have you considered the [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) control? Here's an example of using it: [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx). (The PropertyGrid supports hierarchical structures, but I'm not sure about drag-and-drop)

Comment: @N4TKD I appreciate the link, that does fill in some blanks about object binding. I hadn't considered using the Dictionary. This still leaves the question open of how to populate the TreeView programmatically with the properties of a specific object and its sub-objects without hard-coding it.

Comment: @Arclight personally I like the tag node idea in this case seems easy to impliment.

Comment: Agreed, and if I recall correctly, when performing drag-drop operations from TreeNodes, it is fairly trivial to obtain that tag object.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of behavior in Windows Forms, I'd recommend that you use the [PropertyGrid control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8):

[image: Examples of the PropertyGrid control]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC4364.gif))</sub>

*(Source: [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa302326(v=msdn.10)))*

All you need to do is set the `SelectedObject` property to your custom object and the PropertyGrid will automatically discover your class' properties. It also supports hierarchical objects and editing. Some types, such as Colors, have built-in editors (as depicted above).

The TreeView is not well suited for this kind of automatic binding... though you could write your own code to perform the binding for you using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection).

I've not tried myself, but I beleive that the PropertyGrid's support for Drag'n'Drop is lacking, as evidenced by this post:
[C# PropertyGrid drag drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880298/c-sharp-propertygrid-drag-drop)

Comment: My concern with the use of the PropertyGrid is the exposure of the actual property. I'm not trying to use the TreeView as an editor, but merely as a summary of what properties are available to the end-user for plotting and tabulating. Every property would effectively be a list of numerical values.

Comment: @Arclight - In that case, you'd need to use reflection (since you are binding to the structure of a class rather than the values of an instance).

Comment: So it sounds as though what I'm aiming for is to create a method which uses reflection to take an object, convert its property names into TreeNodes, and then attach the property objects to the nodes via Tags (or one of the other two methods as listed in N4TKD's link post)

Comment: @Arclight - That is probably correct. Unfortunately, there is no easy solution - this is actually a fairly complex requirement. (Consider that both the `string` and `int` types also have properties, so you'd need to filter out your "base types")

Comment: I've actually written some reflection before with the purpose of filtering out specific types. As the lowest-level child nodes will all be the same base type, it shouldn't be too hard to loop through the classes and pull out the information I need. When I get a working version, I'll post it here as an answer for feedback.